# Display items in div on inline didnt worked

Tags: html, css

I got a problem with create page. I created a website and cant figure it out. I paste my html code and also css code.

What i want is header on top, then i will create several photos with information like photo on left, paragraph on right, then reverse and reserve, but i cant figure out my first block of information. In css i got information about my contents of information, then i got info with header, and the div with photo and paragraph and i cant make in display inline-block. Whats wrong? On my container and row i paster informaiton below.Please help me. Also i add image from my current state.

```
   .container {
  margin: auto;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
 <section class="why-we-help">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="home">
                <div class="info">
                    <h1>Dlaczego chcemy pomóc?</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <img class="img" src="images/2.jpg" alt="najwazniejsza jest miłość">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae quisquam id deserunt,
                        enim
                        temporibus autem itaque exercitationem, maiores facere magni minima iure rem facilis
                        adipisci
                        porro debitis, quam ad obcaecati.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

.home {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #000000;
}

.info {
  margin: 35px auto;
}

.info h1 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
 display: inline;
}

.content img {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  width: 50%;
}

.content p {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  width: 50%;
}
```

[image: Photo from page]

Answer (score 1):

Try using  `display:flex` and `flex-direction: row` and `flex-direction: row-reverse`

Comment: flex-direction is the way, just added to .content and everything works fine. Thanks bro

Comment: I'm glad I could help - If it worked, try marking the answer as resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by inline mean side by side horizontally. Just remove the display:inline; property from your .content class.
Like this

```
.content{
  display:flex;
  /*More flex box properties*/
  flex-direction:row;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose this possibility as a result for what you require.

What I did was to change the structure of the code inside the section to give a better understandable order and manage the `css` properties of each element so you can understand how it works.

I`ve also created a header that stays on top if you need something like that.

```css
.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1000 !important;
  
  width: 100%;
  height: 2rem;
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.why-we-help {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.5rem;
  
  height: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  text-align: justify;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.row:nth-of-type(2n) {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.img {
  width: 100%;
}

.row:nth-of-type(2n) .img {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">This is a header that will allways stay on top</div>
<section class="why-we-help">
  <h1 class="title">This is the title of the section</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <img class="img" src="images/2.jpg" alt="Image 1">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae quisquam id deserunt, enim temporibus autem itaque exercitationem, maiores facere magni minima iure rem facilis adipisci porro debitis, quam ad obcaecati.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <img class="img" src="images/2.jpg" alt="Image 2">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae quisquam id deserunt, enim temporibus autem itaque exercitationem, maiores facere magni minima iure rem facilis adipisci porro debitis, quam ad obcaecati.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <img class="img" src="images/2.jpg" alt="Image 1">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae quisquam id deserunt, enim temporibus autem itaque exercitationem, maiores facere magni minima iure rem facilis adipisci porro debitis, quam ad obcaecati.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <img class="img" src="images/2.jpg" alt="Image 2">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae quisquam id deserunt, enim temporibus autem itaque exercitationem, maiores facere magni minima iure rem facilis adipisci porro debitis, quam ad obcaecati.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```